# Rotman's Homological Algebra Problem 3.13(iii)

Tags: homological-algebra

### Problem

[image]

### Corollary 3.13

[image]

### Partial Proof

If $M'$ and $M$ are finitely presented (and therefore finitely generated) it's obvious that $M''$ is finitely presented. If $M$ is finitely presented, then $M'$ is isomorphic to a submodule of $M$, which is finitely presented.

Now suppose $M'$ and $M''$ are finitely presented. I need to show that $M$ is finitely presented...?

Because each module is finitely presented, it follows by definition that they have Euler characteristics.

### Questions

1. How is Corollary 3.13 relevant when one of these modules are finitely presented?
2. Generally not sure how to tackle this problem, though I did get (i) and (ii).

Comment: See my added partial proof. I actually still don't see why Cor 3.13 is relevant!

Comment: I'm not sure why $M'$ is finitely presented, in the first paragraph of your partial proof.

Answer (score 0):

Given the short exact sequence $0 \to M' \to M \to M'' \to 0$, we can choose free resolutions of each so that they fit into short exact sequences at each level: $0 \to F_m' \to F_m \to F_m'' \to 0$. Let's assume that the Euler characteristic exists for two of the three modules. Then there is an $n$ so that two of $F_n'$, $F_n$, and $F_n''$ are zero, and therefore the third is also zero.

It remains to check that for each $m$, if two of $F_m'$, $F_m$, and $F_m''$ are finitely generated, so is the third.

- if $F_m'$ and $F_m$ are finitely generated, then $F_m''$ is a quotient of $F_m$ and so it is finitely generated.
- if $F_m'$ and $F_m''$ are finitely generated, well, we can actually choose free resolutions so that $F_m = F_m' \oplus F_m''$ for each $m$, in which case it is clear that $F_m$ is finitely generated.
- if $F_m$ and $F_m''$ are finitely generated, then we apply Corollary 3.13 to the short exact sequence $0 \to F_m' \to F_m \to F_m'' \to 0$ to conclude that $F_m'$ is finitely generated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the result that says "we can choose free resolutions of each so that they fit into short exact sequences at each level". I don't see this result in Rotman's book. Can you elaborate? Otherwise everything makes sense, except just noting that Rotman doesn't address free resolutions until a later chapter.

Comment: A free resolution is just an exact sequence as in (ii), except it doesn't have to have only finitely many terms, and each term need not be finitely generated.

Comment: I don't have access to Rotman's book, but the "Horseshoe Lemma" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horseshoe_lemma) is one tool that can help; it deals with the second bulleted item in the list.

Comment: I see now that the Horseshoe Lemma is the missing piece, and this makes sense to me! For Bullet Point 2, I just note that for any exact sequence $ 0 \to A \to B \to P \to 0$ with $P$ projective that sequence always splits. So your bullet point 2 is true for *any* choice of free resolution so long as they fit into short exact sequences as you've claimed.